# how to create methods in generic class

Tags: java, generics

```
public class MyArray<V> {
    private ArrayList<V> elements;

    // Creates a MyArray of size "size" and fill it with null objects.
    // Throws NegativeArraySizeException if "size" is negative.
    public MyArray(int size) throws NegativeArraySizeException
```

How can i create this array i'm confused by the generic class used and does filling it with null objects mean to leave it empty?

Comment: OK. Now I saw that after editing.. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/  this tutorial to understand the concept of Generics..

Comment: @NidoAlSaher.. What problem are you facing?? Have you added anything in your constructor??

Answer (score 4):

For a start, there is no need to create a Java array in the code you have presented.  What you need to do is create and fill an `ArrayList<V>`.  And that is simple:

```
public MyArray(int size) throws NegativeArraySizeException {
    elements = new ArrayList<V>(size);  // 'size' is the capacity argument
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        elements.add(null);
    }
}
```

---

As for the other two constructors mentioned in the comment, I fail to see what your difficulty is.  Really it is just straight-forward Java code to call `elements.add` the appropriate number of times with the appropriate arguments.

(I'm not going to give you the code, because either you are already capable of writing it yourself, or alternatively you need to learn how to do it.)

---

> if i make another array called my array and element of strings in it how can i have a copy method to copy elements from the first to second? is there a built in method for that?

This doesn't exactly make sense.  But there are library methods for creating arrays that are copies of existing arrays and collections that are copies of existing collections.  You could use these in your `MyArray` constructors.  Look at the `Arrays` class, the `Collections` class, and the copy constructors of the various collection (i.e. List/Set/Map) implementation classes.

Comment: if i make another array called my array and element of strings in it how can i have a copy method to copy elements from the first to second? is there a built in method for that?

Comment: import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyArray<V> {
private ArrayList<V> elements;

public MyArray(int size) throws NegativeArraySizeException {
    elements = new ArrayList<V>(size);  // 'size' is the capacity argument
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        elements.add(null);
    }
}
// Creates a MyArray and fill it with "array" elements.
public MyArray(V[] array, V String){
 elements = new ArrayList<V> (array.length);
 for(int i =0; i<array.length; i++){
  elements.add(String);
 }
}





}

Comment: and i want to make a copy method that Creates a MyArray whose contents are copies of the "myArr"
// contents.
public MyArray(MyArray<V> myArr){